# Python recursive function doesn't return random choice

Tags: python, recursion, random

I am trying to get random work in python using `random` module. My function is as below:

```
import random

word_file = "/usr/share/dict/words"
WORDS = open(word_file).read().splitlines()


def get_random_word(max_length=None):
    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    print(word)

    if not max_length:
        return word

    if len(word) > max_length:
        get_random_word(max_length)

    return word
```

When I import this function in `ipython` console and run as `get_random_word(max_length=5)`, I get this result:

```
Latasha's
Hammond's
evacuated
aviary
misconducted
airfare's
controllable
unduly
gaunt
Out[32]: "Latasha's"
```

As you see from output, function calls itself until it finds the word with length less than 5. But at the end it returns very first random word. What is wrong with my function?

Comment: Don't use recursion for this. Use a `while` loop.

Comment: @chepner can you explain why? (and please write down you recommended way as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion in Python is inefficient, due to repeated calls to user-defined functions, and limited, in that you will eventually overflow the stack if you don't terminate the recursion soon enough. As such, while the fix to your problem is trivial (return the return value of the recursive call), it's a moot point because recursion is the wrong approach to begin with.

Instead, use a `while` loop to call `random.choice` until you get a word that fits your condition.

```
import random

word_file = "/usr/share/dict/words"
WORDS = open(word_file).read().splitlines()


def get_random_word(max_length=None):
    while True:
        word = random.choice(WORDS)
        if max_length is None or len(word) <= max_length:
            return word
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the return value in your function.

```
        get_random_word(max_length)

    return word
```

should be:

```
    if len(word) > max_length:
        word = get_random_word(max_length)

    return word
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement you need return the value

```
if len(word) > max_length:
        return get_random_word(max_length)
```

the last `return word` will return the last word in memory in this case is the first recursion case of you don't have coincidences because you never return from the base case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple recursion error. The value of the variable word is not retained through recursive calls. You have to assign the return value.

```
word = get_random_word(max_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works, you don't need at all this line `return word` and also you don't need to call `get_random_word` inside print (if you do).